# The underlying provider failed on Open Using WCF?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, wcf

hi i am trying to get consultant list through WCF as i am getting this error as mentioned in title so i would tell you all that code while debug so you get trace place of error ,

as i run form on load i have ,

```
    private void LoadData()
    {
        try
        {
            CIService.CIServiceClient serv = new CIServiceClient();
            serv.GetConsultantListCompleted += new EventHandler<GetConsultantListCompletedEventArgs>(serv_GetConsultantListCompleted);
            serv.GetConsultantListAsync();
            serv.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string error = "<script language=javascript>alert('Failed to Load Consultants at PageLoad \r\n" + ex.StackTrace + "');</script>";
            if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("ConLoadErr"))
                ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "ConLoadErr", error);  
        }
    }

 public ConsultantService():base(connectionString)
        {

        }

    public DataAccessBase(string connectionString)
        {
            this.sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
            this.sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            this.sqlCommand.Connection = this.sqlConnection;
            this.commandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        }

  List<Consultant> ICIService.GetConsultantList()
        {
            ConsultantService service = new ConsultantService();
            return service.GetConsultantList();
        }

    public List<Consultant> GetConsultantList()
        {
            DataAccessManager.SystemSetup sysSetup = new SystemSetup();
            return sysSetup.GetConsultantList();
        }

 public List<Consultant> GetConsultantList()
        {
            InspectionEntities dbContext = new InspectionEntities();
            return dbContext.Consultants.ToList();
        }

    public InspectionEntities() : 
                base("name=InspectionEntities", "InspectionEntities")
        {
            this.OnContextCreated();
        }

  public List<Consultant> GetConsultantList()
        {
            InspectionEntities dbContext = new InspectionEntities();
            return dbContext.Consultants.ToList();
        }
```

On returning to it again it give error on "return dbContext.Consultants.ToList();"

```
Inner Exception ({"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)"})
```

and

```
Stack Trace

   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at DataAccessManager.SystemSetup.GetConsultantList() in G:\Design Scoring\DataAccessManager\SystemSetup.cs:line 42
   at InspectionServices.ConsultantService.GetConsultantList() in G:\Design Scoring\InspectionServices\Services\ConsultantService.cs:line 112
   at InspectionServices.CIService.InspectionServices.ICIService.GetConsultantList() in G:\Design Scoring\InspectionServices\CIService.cs:line 253
   at SyncInvokeGetConsultantList(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
```

Hopes for your suggestion

Thanks

EDITED:one more thing i wanna mention that on other forms of this application i am getting data from db with out any error